# How to customize fortify visual studio plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortify

I am very new to HP Fortify SCA tool. I have Fortify plugin for Visual Studio 2010 installed. Now if I start analyzing the code, it includes all project in that solution. But I have lot of test projects which I want to exclude from analysis. If anyone has any idea how to customize the list of projects which need to be included for analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the projects from scanning by setting them not to build from the solution configuration.

For example, one way to accomplish this is:

1. *Build* -> *clean solution*
2. Highlight solution, right click and select *Properties*
3. Select *configuration properties* (ensure configuration is set to debug)
4. uncheck the *build* column of each project you do not wish to scan

Now when you scan in debug mode, you will not be translating/scanning the projects that are not set to build in that configuration.

Hope this helps.